# JSF preRenderView not triggered when navigating to page without using Redirect

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, java-ee-6, icefaces-3

I have created a preRender method to be called when the user navigate to that specific page, I use:

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:event listener="#{targetClass.prerender()}"
        type="preRenderView">
    </f:event>
</f:metadata>
```

but the problem is that this method is not being called when I navigate to this page, unless I use

```
<redirect />
```

in the faces-config.xml file.
But, I don't want to use redirect, so the url always point to the login page.

Thank you.

Comment: is your `f:metadata` a [direct child](http://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.0/pdldocs/facelets/f/metadata.html) of `f:view`?

Comment: can you post your complete xhtml and also the prerender method

Comment: My `f:metadata` is a direct child of `h:head` , I also tried it inside `h:body` and tried `f:event` without `f:metadata`, and I got the same result. The only way it work is when I use `redirect` in the navigation case.

Comment: `<html xmlns="http://....
<h:head>
 <f:metadata>
  <f:event listener="#{Login.prerender()}" type="preRenderView"></f:event>
 </f:metadata>
</h:head>
<h:body>
 <ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/templates/common.xhtml">
  <ui:define name="content">
   <ice:panelGroup id="loginPanelGroup" >
    <ice:outputLabel binding="#{Login.loginUsernameLabel}"
     id="loginUsernameLabel" value="Login name" />
    <ice:inputText binding="#{Login.loginUsernameInput}" label=""
     id="loginUsernameInput" maxlength="8" required="true" />
   </ice:panelGroup>
  </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
</h:body>
</html>`

Comment: public void prerender() {
     log.debug("Login.prerender " + this);
    }

Comment: Just to make sure, did also try "preRenderComponent"?